# Getting templatefields out of string with regex

Tags: regex, template-engine

Can anyone tell me how to use regex to get templatefields out of a string?

The fields in the string are marked `%%word%%`, with one word between the percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the "%" characters: \%\%(.*?)\%\%

This will return the match in group(1), use nextFind() or something like that to get to the next string.

Answer (score 2):

```
%%(\w+)%%
```

matches `%%`, followed by one or more alphanumerics, followed by `%%`.

Match group 0 (often referred to as `$0`) will contain the entire match; group 1 (`$1`) will contain the matched word.

Comment: Don't use lookarounds, or things like `%%foo%%bar%%` will match too.

Comment: @Qtax: Good point; if strings like those could occur, we'd have a problem either way, though - which one would be the right string?

Comment: That would be defined by the specification or the implementation (logically the first one found). Consider `igot%%foo%%and%%bar%%too`, I see no problem there, nor do I think that `and` should match.